# Is there any way of generating java.awt.Image out of an .xsd Schema?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-rs

I have this big doubt.
When ever i use base64Binary in an .xsd schema and use JaxB to transform it to a Java class, the type i get is byte[].

I want to create such schema that the java type being generated out of it is java.awt.Image.
Is this possible?

I tried something like this:

```
<element name="name" type="base64Binary" xmime:expected(entreTypes = "image/jpeg")/>
```

The result was byte[].

I know that out a java.awt.Image if i transform into an schema i get just

```
<element name="name" type="base64Binary"/>
```

But is there any way to get it java.awt.Image out of the .xsd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your the element declaration in your XML schema to look like the following to generate an `java.awt.Image` type:

```
<xsd:element name="name"
    type="xsd:base64Binary"
    xmime:expectedContentTypes="image/jpeg"/>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/schema-to-java-xmlmimetype.html

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for. I knew it was possible.
 I've tried it, but didn't work, i got some exception regarding to the content type. Now i will read that blog post and try to implement it again. Now at least i know it is possible :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What will be actually stored in the XML, the image encoded in JPEG?

You can use [`Toolkit.createImage(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage%28byte%5B%5D%29) to create a `java.awt.Image` from JPEG data.

Or, if you need a `BufferedImage`, you can wrap the byte array in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and use [`ImageIO.read(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) to read it.

Comment: I see, yes but my doubt is. If is there any way that can make the <element> transformed into an Image when JaxB compiles the schema?

Comment: What would the jaxb compiler do with the image?

Comment: Nothing just i want to know how the syntax of the element in the schema should look like, so the xjc compiler can transform it into a java.awt.Image field. I am wondering if is that possible? because i always get a byte[] but i want an Image object automatically generated.